# Small script to re-create a file indefinitely

Tags: ruby, file

I created a small ruby script at work to recreate a text file I use for a test in the Java application we are supporting.

I'm still really new to the ruby paradigm and wanted to know if that small script respect most of the spirit of it.

The content of the file doesn't need to make sense since the only requirement I have is that a file exist.

Since I'm doing my test every minute mostly, I set the sleeping time between checking the existence of the file to 30 seconds.

```
require 'pathname'

PATH = "C:/folder/to/file/test1.txt"
SLEEP_TIME = 30

path_to_text_file = Pathname.new(PATH)
while (true)
  unless path_to_text_file.exist? then
    File.open(PATH, "w") {|f| f.write("test") }
    puts "File #{PATH} created"
  end
  puts "Sleeping for #{SLEEP_TIME} seconds"
  sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
end
```

Could I do better? I'm on Windows and using JRuby, is there something I'm missing with my code being portable ?

Obvisously, I could make the path an argument of my script, but I don't need this at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine overall! You can skip `Pathname` however, and do something like this instead:

```
PATH = "C:/folder/to/file/test1.txt"
SLEEP_TIME = 30

while true
  unless File.exist?(PATH)
    File.open(PATH, "w") { |io| io.write("test") }
    puts "File #{PATH} created"
  end
  puts "Sleeping for #{SLEEP_TIME} seconds"
  sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
end
```

Comment: When I read about file reading and other things about it, it said that `Pathname` was a good multi-os way of managing file path. I tested your version on my Windows, but is there some particular things if I would run this script in a *nix system ?

Comment: @Marc-Andre I'm on OS X myself, so no issues on a *nix system. The code is all just Ruby stdlib, so it's portable. And yes, `Pathname` is great for cross-platform path inspection and manipulation, but here the path is just a const string - no manipulation needed. If the path's valid on the computer you're using, it'll work. If it isn't, well, then it won't work. So in a sense, the script isn't portable _at all_ without being tailored for a specific machine - not just OS - before being run. But the code itself is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you really want to reinvent the wheel, you could use `FileUtils.touch` for this:

> `FileUtils.touch`
>
> Updates modification time (mtime) and access time (atime) of file(s) in list. Files are created if they don’t exist.

For example:

```
require 'fileutils'

PATH = "C:/folder/to/file/test1.txt"
SLEEP_TIME = 30

loop do
  FileUtils.touch(PATH)
  sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Rather than just dumping the docs and some code on the asker, a few human words go a long way to making a post much better! (see my edit) In any case, nice answer +1